# how to increase time out in forms authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have small doubt in forms authentication. How to increase timeout in forms authentication in asp.net website? In my website, I set  `<forms loginUrl="Default.aspx"  name=".ASPXAUTH" timeout="60000" protection="All">`. But if we refresh the page after 15 min it's redirecting to default page. Could you suggest me any one, how to resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is this issue ?? or you want just to increase the time span of the form. Clarify it properly

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the timeout value to be longer, you can easily change the timeout value in your local web.config file (the timeout value is in minutes):

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms timeout="50000000"/>
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Auth/SignOn.aspx" timeout="40" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

On a side note you should make `TimeOut(Session) less than or equal to TimeOut(FormsAuthentication) * 2`